# Teradata - Change format of Sequenced Validtime period

Tags: sql, teradata, sql-timestamp

I have the following query:

```
SEQUENCED VALIDTIME PERIOD '(2017-11-06,2017-11-10)' 
SELECT a, b, c, 
d, e, f 
FROM table_1
```

This creates a table with columns `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f` and `VALIDTME`. The `VALIDTIME`column contains data similar to `(2017-11-09 07:17:03.120000-05:00, 2017-11-10 00:00:00.000000-05:00)`. How can I modify my query to obtain this data as `11/09/2017 07:17:03, 11/10/2017 00:00:00`? Ideally, I would like to split this timestamp as two columns: `start time` and `end time`. However, the techniques that work on normal columns doesn't seem to work on `VALIDTIME`. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your temporal table should have a column with a PERIOD data type designated as your VALIDTIME column.  I think there are helper functions you can use with the VALIDTIME column, like `BEGIN()` and `END()`, to extract the values you want.  Once you do that, you should be able to format however you like.  Something like:

```
SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,
  CAST(BEGIN(ValidTime_Column) AS DATE FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS'),
  CAST(END(ValidTime_Column) AS DATE FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS')
FROM table_1
```

I don't have a TD system to check, so you may get a syntax error.  Give it a  try and let me know if it works.

Comment: Sorry about the delay in response. It throws an error: `expected something between '(' and the 'VALIDTIME' keyword.` How can I tell TOAD / Teradata that I want to specify `VALIDTIME` as a column not keyword?

Comment: No problem.  Find the DDL for your table and you'll see one column should be specified as VALIDTIME.  That's the column name you want to use.  If you can't get it to work, please post your DDL and the query you're trying.

Comment: I saw the column. It is named `VALIDTIME`, which is also a keyword. I tried adding using double quotes while specifying the column. I received an error saying I can't use the column while using `SEQUENCED VALIDTIME PERIOD`.

Comment: Also, just to be sure, DDL refers to table details? (Sorry, new to databases).

Comment: Hmm...Yes, DDL means the table definition.  Can you do a `SHOW TABLE <table_name>` and post the output?  You may need to qualify the table name <db_name>.<table_name>

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to do it.

Comment: What if you try running as NONSEQUENCED VALIDTIME?  Do you still get the same error?

`NONSEQUENCED VALIDTIME SELECT a,b,...`

This will ignore the temporal aspect and treat the table like a regular table.

Comment: This table is to be used in a Python script. So I am now planning to handle this in the script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163904/discussion-between-ravioli-and-skr-robo).